# TypeScript recursive types cause errors

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The minimal code to reproduce this problem is as follows:

```js
type Head<T> = T extends [infer U,...unknown[]] ? U : never;
type Tail<T> = T extends [unknown,...infer U] ? U : [];


type Converter = null;
type Convert<T, U extends Converter> = T;


type ConvChain<BaseType, T extends Converter[]> = 
    T extends [Converter]
    ? Convert<BaseType, Head<T>>
    : Head<T> extends Converter 
        ? ConvChain<Convert<BaseType, Head<T>>, Tail<T>>
        : never;

type ThisWillBeError = ConvChain<unknown, Converter[]>;
```

Type `ThisWillBeError` will throw the following error:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

I would like to resolve this error.

### Explanation about the code

`Head<T>` ... Extracts the first element of an array
`Tail<T>` ... Extracts the elements of an array except the first element.

`Convert<T, U extends Converter>` / `Converter` ...
Applies the specific transformation indicated by type `U` to type `T`.
In the code I wrote, there is a more complicated type here, but I did so because I could also reproduce the problem by returning `T` regardless of the type `U` that was the directive.
The type `U` that gives the instruction must also satisfy the type `Converter`.

`ConvChain` ...
Converters given to type "T" are applied to BaseType in turn.
Example:
`ConvChain<Test, [A, B, C]>` = `Convert<Convert<Convert<Test, A>, B>, C>`

### Why do I need this type `ThisWillBeError`?

If I want the same work that type "Convert" does, I think the following generic function like this will be needed:

```js
function someFunc<Convs extends Converter[], Base>(x: Base, convs: Convs): ConvChain<Base, Convs>  {
    return /* result */ as ConvChain<Base, Convs>;
}
```

This ConvChain<Base, Convs> causes the same error as above. I believe these are caused by the same thing.

### What I have tried

I assumed that there is an upper limit to the number of array elements that can be passed to a `ConvChain` (recursive type).
I produced the following one, which passes only five or less Converters:

```js
type ThisWillBeError = ConvChain<unknown, [
    ...([Converter] | []),
    ...([Converter] | []),
    ...([Converter] | []),
    ...([Converter] | []),
    ...([Converter] | []),
]>;
```

This was still an error, but for some reason it worked correctly when I made it accept 1 to 5 parameters.

```js
type ThisWorks = ConvChain<unknown, [
    Converter,
    ...([Converter] | []),
    ...([Converter] | []),
    ...([Converter] | []),
    ...([Converter] | []),
]>;
```

However, if possible, `Converter` would also like to allow empty arrays.
Furthermore, we do not want to set a maximum number here.
(In other words, I want it to error only when I pass an array that exceeds the TS limit to the generic of the function.)

### Other information

My environment is Typescript v4.8.4.
I have confirmed that I can reproduce the problem with v4.2.3 to v4.9.4.

(I am a Japanese student, sorry if my English is incorrect!)

Comment: Recursive conditional types (especially distributive ones) can easily trip the circularity detectors.  Whenever possible you should replace conditional types with unconditional versions.  For example, `Head<T>` does not need to be conditional; you can directly access the `0` index of an array/tuple.  If I change that, [as shown here](//tsplay.dev/WPzgkN), then the error goes away.  It is quite possible that your actual use case is not solved by this, but that's usually the first step I take. Does that address your question fully? If so I will write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I just tried it in the environment at hand, 
I replaced all `Head<T>`s in the `ConvChain` with `T[0]` and the error went away!
I think my question is fully resolved.
I'm looking forward your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) are very powerful, but such deeply nested type manipulation can easily run afoul of the compiler's circularity detection mechanisms.  Often it is possible to refactor an offending type to a working version, but (in my experience) this is more of an art than a science.

One step I normally take is to try to eliminate any *unnecessarily* conditional type.  If you can replace a conditional type with some combination of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), or the like, you might improve things enough to fix the error.

For instance, in your code example, the following type definition:

```
type Head<T> = T extends [infer U, ...unknown[]] ? U : never;
```

is unnecessarily conditional.  Instead of using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) on a variadic tuple type, you can look up the property at element `0` of `T` directly via indexed access, as long as  `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an appropriate type like `readonly any[]`:

```
type Head<T extends readonly any[]> = T[0];
```

This should hopefully evaluate to the same thing in most/all cases you care about:

```
type X = Head<["a", "b", "c"]> // "a" for either definition
```

(and if it doesn't then you should be careful around such edge cases)  And with this definition, your original example code no longer produces an error.

```
type ThisWillBeError = ConvChain<unknown, Converter[]>; // no error now
```

This happens to solve the problem with the example code.  It's quite possible that a reader with a similar issue will not be lucky enough to find a simple substitution like this, or the substitution will not resolve the error.  But because it's more of an art than a science, it's hard to make recommendations in the abstract.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhCGATA8gJwJYHMA8AVAfFALxS5QQAewEAdogM5QDa6NAZhKlAKoA0UAOiEBXGgGsaAewDuNJgF15UAPw8oALig0IAN04BuAFCHQkKAA1kxWAhQYcTAETxH-RwCNXURwGNH8-BNwaHNrOCRsJxc3Tzc-AKgAekTvF2NTaHDEPHIqWgYoVFtJGgAbECh4GhAFQhJcJgAGeSMM0nh0Urw60lzqOkYmUQkZGn4hAVYOLm4lVW4NZhb04KgAYRK9VGouEhphUtLW1Y2aLeA8fgXKfoLT884e3CMVs3u1gAsOmmwAIXh6BBcMF+GQbvlGPdODtasRDFBeuCBswodtOPJ4Sp1ptoX8AUCQTYIgRAgjNFlun0IdiztDOJjVO8vqxsKiLv9AcDIPwKSTQR0uiTMZptFsXm1cB90PQAOqdUq-CAAUVQqEkuxpOk+32wwyksn4bM4tX0SRSUnIqvVWhkQA)